# Notifications not working on Whitelabel iOS Rocket.chat app

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, notifications

So I am whitelabeling the Rocket.chat app for iOS. I have already done this for Android and it is working very well. The issue I'm having is that the app works on the simulator, but it does not receive any notifications. I have followed [these instructions](https://developer.rocket.chat/mobile-app/mobile-app-white-labelling/ios-app-white-labelling) to no avail. It seems as if the app is not able to communicate with Firebase. Additionally, when I first launch the app after installing, it asks if I want to enable notifications, so the app itself is working. I'm really not sure what to try next. Thank you for your help. If you need any additional information, just let me know.

Comment: The simulator cannot receive push notifications. You will need to run on a real iOS device

Comment: Oh really? That's seems a little strange but makes sense why they haven't been working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the simulator cannot receive push notifications. Seems strange, but that was the problem.